# Executing a specific method daily in Swift

Tags: swift, parsing

I was wondering how you would go about having a function that executes once a day. In my case I would like users to answer a daily question and the answer will stay with the user for a day. The next day, a new question will be asked and so on. I've been told that you cannot execute functions when the user is not using the app. So I was wondering if there is a way to set a timer (e.g. a 24-hour) that expires and essentially deletes the answer? If there is any way you would go about this issue, I would really appreciate learning form you guys.

Currently I am using Parse.com to retrieve my questions and I am unsure whether or not I should save the answers back in parse or have them as NSUserDefaults because I don't know how to go about the issue stated above.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of approaches:

- Local notifications: You can schedule a local notification that (if the user grants notification privileges to the app) will present a notification to the user at some predetermined time. If the user taps on the notification, the app will be opened. (If the user doesn't tap on the notification, though, the app will not be opened.)

  See [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1).
- Background fetch: You can have the app request background fetch capabilities, in which the OS will allow the app to make very quick network requests to see if there is any data to retrieve. You can combine this with local notifications to let the user know when there is new question available. Note, you cannot control the timing of this, so it's not guaranteed to take place daily, much less at a consistent time every day. Nonetheless, this is an easy way for the app to check for new data without the user having to run the app themselves.

  See [Fetching Small Amounts of Data Opportunistically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW56) in the *App Programming Guide for iOS.*
- Related to the local notifications, you could also entertain using push notifications (where your web service would proactively notify the user when there was new question available). This push notification service is discussed in the aforementioned [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1).
- When the user starts up the app, you can compare the current date and time to the date and time associated with the last known question to see whether you present the last question or whether you initiate network request to get the next one.
- Regarding where to store the answers, `NSUserDefaults` is almost certainly the wrong place. If you want to save it locally, save it to persistent storage (an archive or the like) or use Core Data. Saving it back to the network has the virtue, though, of the possibility to synchronize the state of the app's questions and answers across devices.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it either way (saving it in Parse or `NSUserDefaults`). As for presenting a question once a day, you'd need to first make sure you timestamp once every time the user answers a question, then check if your last timestamp is greater than 24 hours.

So, you'd (roughly) say something like this:

**Obj-C:**

```
const uint DAY_IN_SECONDS = 24 * 60 * 60;
if (fabs([lastTimeTheUserAnsweredTimestamp timeIntervalSinceNow]) > DAY_IN_SECONDS) {
   // present today's question.
} else {
   // you've already answered today's question.
}
```

**Swift:**

```
let DAY_IN_SECONDS = 24 * 60 * 60;
if (fabs(lastTimeTheUserAnsweredTimestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow()) > DAY_IN_SECONDS) {
   // present today's question.
} else {
   // you've already answered today's question.
}
```

This of course assumes `lastTimeTheUserAnsweredTimestamp` is an NSDate.

Comment: just to clarify. Is the code above written in objective-C or swift?

Comment: Obj-C however it's extremely simple to convert to Swift. (just added swift).